# Calling function with spread operator

Tags: typescript

Why this simple code

```
const arr: [string, number] = ['str', 1];

function fn(arg1?: string, arg2?: number): void {
    alert(arg1);
}

fn(...arr);
```

produces this error:

> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
>     Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

When I change my call to

```
fn(arr[0], arr[1])
```

everything works fine.

Why spread does not work as expected?
Why type is also converted to 'string | number'?
Shouldn't it detect that the first one is a string and the latter is a number?

Answer (score 1):

Good find. This has already been picked up as a bug by the Typescript community:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4130

It looks like they are still working on it.